# ammo.js collision cloth with soft body

Tags: three.js, collision, ammo.js

I'm using ammo.js in three.js and made experiments with cloth (simple table cloth) falling down on  1° rigid body and 2° soft body. Cloth collides well with rigid body but does not detect soft body and simply crosses the soft body. What could I have made wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass needs more area to resist force. The cloth must be thicker, or else make use of hidden helper geometries which assume the position(s) of key vertices. These will displace the volume, depending on your unit scale, mass, and other forces.

There is a dancing anime character in three.js/examples which uses IK. Look at the hidden rigging and notice the weights the bones have for hair. It is an artistic expression.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ; I gave a look to the dancing girl. I guess it is the mmd demo. I'm not familiar with mmd but I nevertheless managed to import the model in Blender. My understanding is that to run the animation the physics in three.js uses ammo anchor points on clothes. In my case, attaching the cloth to an anchor point is also working. But I neved saw a demo where the cloth (softbody plane) collides with another softbody volume. By the way what do you mean with "cloth must be thicker ?". Cloth is created by  softBodyHelpers.CreatePatch which I guess creates a plane and not a volume ?

Comment: The mmd demo is an example of rigging... I'm saying for a cloth plane to collide with another cloth plane, you may need helper volume geometry(s). Of course it depends on your flavor of ammo.js and specific tolerances. But as you notice a cloth plane gets tangled and intersects itself at extreme values. Cloth shows that, despite friction or mass, the simulation step has finite bounds -- but you can also use physics to shove a sphere through a wall if you abuse a normal tolerance. So with cloth, make some helper volumes with enough area, since area is a huge part of the calculation.

Comment: OK thanks ; I think it becomes now clearer : Volume geometry helper needed for cloth   to manage collision with other soft bodies. Thanks.